# Сложная выборка из нескольких таблиц SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть следующие таблицы, в каждой из которых реализована связь "один ко многим", то есть слову из каждой предыдущей таблицы может соответствовать несколько значений из последующих таблиц:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c9fe4/2

**wordNames** — базовая таблица-хранилище слов

- `word_id`: *integer* — id слова — пример: `1`
- `word_name`: *varchar* — запись слова — пример: `journey`

**langedWords** — таблица связи слов с языками, т. е. одно и то же слово может принадлежать разным языкам

- `word_id`: *integer* — id словоформы из `wordNames`
- `langed_word_id`: *integer* — идентификатор получившегося слова в контексте языка
- `lang_id`: *integer*  — идентификатор языка

**posedWords**  — таблица связи слов ( PoS — part of speech — часть речи) с частями речи: одно и то же слово может принадлежать разным частям речи. Яркий пример: `can` — мочь, уметь (глаг.), банка (сущ.)

- `langed_word_id`: *integer* — слово в контексте языка из `langedWords`
- `posed_word_id`: *integer* — слово в контексте части речи
- `pos_id`: *integer* — идентификатор части речи

**lex** — таблица слов (лексем) в контексте их значения: одно и то же по написанию слово данной части речи может нести разные лексические значения

- `posed_word_id`: *integer* — идентификатор варианта слова в контексте его части речи
- `lex_id`: *integer* — идентификатор слова, обладающего конкретным значением

**translations** — таблица переводов

- `lex_transl_id`: *integer*  — фиктивный ключ
- `lex_id`: *integer* — id слова, перевод которого представлен в строке
- `lang_id`: *integer* — id языка, перевод на который происходит
- `transl_id`: *integer* — id слова из данного целевого языка. Точно так же является внешним `lex_id` из таблицы `lex`

Собственно, проблема такова:
Организовать выборку из `translations` таким образом, чтобы заместо идентификаторов показывались записи слов `word_names` из таблицы `wordNames`.

Пример:
Ожидается получить колонки `Word` и `Translation`, в которых будут представлены пары вида "слово — перевод" как они есть в таблице `translations`, то есть:

```
book — книга
art — искусство
race — гонка
```

Удалось осуществить задумку лишь частично и, как кажется, криво. Конкретно: получилось выводить одновременно (корректно) лишь одну колонку ("слово" или "перевод"). При попытке объединить колонки в единое представление значения перемножаются, поскольку нет поля, по которому проверялось бы их соответствие. Как вариант — использовать фиктивный `lex_transl_id` из таблицы `translations`, но я не имею понятия, как это сделать. Кроме этого, было предположение о том, что стоит при каждой выборке создавать временную таблицу с полями для записей слов и их переводов, однако я сомневаюсь, что это имеет смысл.

Попытка вывести две колонки вместе:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c9fe4/2

```sql
SELECT first.word_name as 'Word', second.word_name as 'Translation'
FROM wordNames as first, wordNames as second
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT llangw.langed_word_id, llangw.word_id
    FROM 'langedWords' as llangw

    INNER JOIN (

        SELECT lposw.posed_word_id, lposw.langed_word_id
        FROM 'posedWords' as lposw

        INNER JOIN (

            SELECT llex.lex_id, llex.posed_word_id
            FROM 'lex' as llex 

                INNER JOIN (

                    SELECT ltransl.lex_id
                    FROM 'translations' as ltransl

                ) left_transl ON (llex.lex_id = left_transl.lex_id)

        ) left_lex ON (lposw.posed_word_id = left_lex.posed_word_id)

    ) left_posed ON (llangw.langed_word_id = left_posed.langed_word_id)

) left_langed ON (first.word_id = left_langed.word_id)

INNER JOIN (

    SELECT rlangw.langed_word_id, rlangw.word_id
    FROM 'langedWords' as rlangw

    INNER JOIN (

        SELECT rposw.posed_word_id, rposw.langed_word_id
        FROM 'posedWords' as rposw

        INNER JOIN (

            SELECT rlex.lex_id, rlex.posed_word_id
            FROM 'lex' as rlex 

                INNER JOIN (

                    SELECT rtransl.transl_id FROM 'translations' as rtransl

                ) right_transl ON (rlex.lex_id = right_transl.transl_id)

        ) right_lex ON (rposw.posed_word_id = right_lex.posed_word_id)

    ) right_posed ON (rlangw.langed_word_id = right_posed.langed_word_id)

) right_langed ON (second.word_id = right_langed.word_id);
```

Запрос, с помощью которого удается вывести левый столбец (практически аналогичен правому):

```sql
SELECT first.word_name as 'Word' FROM wordNames as first
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT llangw.langed_word_id, llangw.word_id
    FROM 'langedWords' as llangw

    INNER JOIN (

        SELECT lposw.posed_word_id, lposw.langed_word_id
        FROM 'posedWords' as lposw

        INNER JOIN (

            SELECT llex.lex_id, llex.posed_word_id
            FROM 'lex' as llex 

                INNER JOIN (

                    SELECT ltransl.lex_id
                    FROM 'translations' as ltransl

                ) left_transl ON (llex.lex_id = left_transl.lex_id)

        ) left_lex ON (lposw.posed_word_id = left_lex.posed_word_id)

    ) left_posed ON (llangw.langed_word_id = left_posed.langed_word_id)

) left_langed ON (first.word_id = left_langed.word_id);
```

Прошу разобраться в проблеме и помочь новичку в sql составить корректный sql-запрос. Будет прекрасно, если можно написать запрос совсем по-другому, проще, в том случае если иной способ эффективнее, поскольку каждая таблица будет насчитывать в первое время точно более тысячи записей, в дальнейшем — десятки тысяч.

Comment: что такое `5 — 14` и что такое `journey — путешествие`? уточните, пожалуйста, в самом вопросе. возможно, пример данных, хранящихся в ваших таблицах, поможе понять, что же вам требуется.

Comment: Используй билдеры sql запросов. Я сам при помощи такого строю и сразу проверяю. Юзаю rapid sql. Попробуй мож поможет. Для меня дак полный напряг делать сложные запросы.

Comment: нет, без образца данных вряд ли у кого-то хватит терпения вникать в вашу предметную область. я [набросал](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b18d0b) описанные вами таблицы и добавил в первую из них две пары строк. дополните, пожалуйста, остальные таблицы минимальным набором **связных** данных и опубликуйте получившуюся ссылку (после нажатия кнопки «build schema»). так будет значительно проще вам помочь с требующимся запросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я смог правильно понять схему и примеры запросов, то тогда нужный Вам запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
select wwn.word_name as 'word', twn.word_name as 'translate'
from translations t
join lex wl on wl.lex_id = t.lex_id
join lex tl on tl.lex_id = t.transl_id
join posedWords wpw on wpw.posed_word_id = wl.posed_word_id
join posedWords tpw on tpw.posed_word_id = tl.posed_word_id
join langedWords wlw on wlw.langed_word_id = wpw.langed_word_id
join langedWords tlw on tlw.langed_word_id = tpw.langed_word_id
join wordNames wwn on wwn.word_id = wlw.word_id
join wordNames twn on twn.word_id = tlw.word_id
```

Comment: Превосходно! Написанный Вами запрос — как раз то, что мне требуется. Отнюдь буду идти в данном направлении. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!